# What does this red seal and picture say or mean? (Characters identified: 天天快樂，前程似錦)

Tags: translation

[image]

Please help me find out what this means as live to know artists to find out what a piece of art means

Answer (score 2):

The writing: 天天快樂 (happy everyday)

The seal: 前程似錦 (have a bright future)

No signature in the picture you posted